# Ansible consume AD command output

Tags: list, dictionary, active-directory, ansible

i got a problem how to consume the following command output in Ansible

basically im trying to get the list of Active Directory OUs and loop over that list to search for specific name. My script works well when multiple OUs exists but i have an issue when only single OU exists. Explained below

```
    tasks:
  - name: PS - Pull System OUs from AD 
    win_command: powershell - 
    args:
      stdin: "Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchScope 1  -SearchBase 'OU=SYSTEMS,DC=domain,DC=int' -Server domain.int | select-object name | ConvertTo-json"
    become: yes
    register: ou_reg_out      

  - name: Select Systems OU
    block:
    - name: Set list of standardized OUs as facts
      set_fact:
        ou_reg_list: "{{ ou_reg_out.stdout  }}"

    - name: Set System OU for system
      set_fact:
        ou_name: "OU={{item.name}}"
      loop: "{{ ou_reg_list }}"
      when: (item.name|upper) == (srv_type|upper)
    when: ou_reg_out.stdout|length != 0
```

basically i need to be able to loop over the ou_reg_out.stdout.
It works when command returns multiple OUs as ou_reg_out.stdout returns list:

```
ou_reg_out.stdout:
  - { name: OU1 }
  - { name: OU2 }
```

issue is when only single OU exists , command doesnt return the list

```
ou_reg_out.stdout:
  { name: OU1 }
```

Any idea how to workaround this problem ?

Comment: Are those examples the *actual* output of the `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` command? Because that's not valid JSON (which I was expecting, given the `ConvertTo-json` at the end).

Comment: actually the debug of output with from_json filter looks like below - thats when multiple OUs exists

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "ou_reg_out.stdout | from_json": [
        {
            "name": "OU1"
        },
        {
            "name": "OU2"
        },
        {
            "name": "OU3"
   ]
}

when single OU exists the output looks like this 
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "list": {
        "name": "OU1"
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the [type of the variable](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/?highlight=iterable#mapping) and branch the code.

[json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter helps to select the items from the list. Then [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) helps to conditionally select the value. The value of the first item that matches the condition is used. Defaults to 'NOTFOUND'.

For example the play bellow for both versions of `ou_reg_list`

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    ou_reg_list:
      - { name: OU1 }
      - { name: OU2 }
#   ou_reg_list:
#     { name: OU1 }
    srv_type: 'ou1'

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ou_name: "OU={{ (ou_reg_list.name == srv_type|upper)|
                        ternary( ou_reg_list.name, 'NOTFOUND') }}"
      when: ou_reg_list is mapping

    - block:

        - set_fact:
            ou_names: "{{ ou_reg_list|json_query(query) }}"
          vars:
            query: "[?name=='{{ srv_type|upper }}'].name"

        - set_fact:
            ou_name: "OU={{ (ou_names|length > 0)|
                            ternary( ou_names.0, 'NOTFOUND') }}"
      when: ou_reg_list is not mapping

    - debug:
        var: ou_name
```

gives

```
"ou_name": "OU=OU1"
```

Comment: I just tested your solution. Problem is that when AD command returns only single item ( 1 OU in the hierarchy) - the JSON result doesnt come back as list. the format is TASK [debug] ******************************************************************* ok: [host] => { "list": { "name": "OU1" } }
and when i try your solution the ou_names comes out as null

Comment: @Marek. Right. I've branched the code on this condition.